# How to get the raw pointer of a shared_ptr in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

I'm working with a C library and would like to covert an object pointer to a shared_ptr. Say the C library has...

```
T* CreateObject();
void DoStuff(T*);
void DestroyObject(T*);
```

Then I can do...

```
std::shared_ptr<T> sptr(CreateObject(), DestroyObject);
```

While I can put the pointer from the CreateObject method into a shared_ptr, and call the DestroyObject method with a custom deleter, there is the issue of accessing the raw pointer to call DoStuff. I noticed the shared_ptr::get() method but it was removed in C++17 as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, it's still there: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.get()` still exists

Comment: Unless you specifically *need* shared ownership you may want to consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr::get()` still exists in C++17.

Its definition was [merely refined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get).

Before C++17, it returned `T*`.  Since C++17, it returns [`std::remove_extent_t<T>*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent).

This change was made to mirror `boost::shared_ptr`'s [handling of arrays](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3640.html).

You may still use it.